# declaring an array vs allocating memory for it

Tags: c, malloc

I wrote a function in C that takes 10 integer from the user and prints them out.

```
void memoryallocationtest(int number)
{
    // allocate space for 10 integer
    char *input = malloc( 32 * sizeof(char) );
    long *x = malloc( number * sizeof(long) );
    char *ptr;

    printf("please enter 10 integer X consecutively, -2147483648 <= X <= 2147483647)\n");
    /* promts user to enter ith integer
     * converts input string to long value and saves result in x
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        printf( "%i. Integer:", (i + 1) );
        scanf( "%s", input );
        x[i] = strtol( input, &ptr, 10 );
    }
    free(x);
    free(input);
}
```

Is this an efficient way to do it?

Is there any point of allocating and freeing space for my char-array "input" or should I just declare it like `char input[32];` or is that what happens implicit anyway?

Comment: If you really are limiting your input to `32` chars and the number of integers to `10`, there is no need to dynamically allocate `input` (it's not returned). In fact nothing is being returned. You only need to dynamically allocate, objects declared in `memoryallocationtest` that you wish to return a pointer to. I would simply use `char input[32] = "";` and if you are returning `x`, then your allocation of `x` is fine, but change your function type to `long *`, and return `x`. (`free(x);` sort of defeats the purpose doesn't it?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That seems a decent answer. Can we get this out of the list of unanswered questions?

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment:

While your technical understanding of the syntax and proper use of memory allocation functions is fine, the function you provided does not make much sense. Static declaration of local variables will always be faster (e.g. more efficient) than dynamically allocating memory (if just by virtue of saving the function call overhead).

The choice between *"Do I need to dynamically allocate?"* is largely governed by (1) *"is it too big to fit on the stack?"*, and (2) *"what is the lifetime needed for the stored values?"* [**C11 Standard (draft n1570) §6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Your function (type `void`) returns no value and does nothing with the 10 `int` values stored in `x`. In that regard, as written, there is no need to dynamically allocate anything. Simply declaring a character array and array of long will provide *automatic storage duration* (e.g. for the life of function (e.g. scope) whithin which they are declared). As such, a more efficient implementation of your function would simply declare `char input[32] = "";` and `long x[10] = {0};`

**Note:** when you declare arrays within a function, the memory for the array is only guaranteed to exist during the life of the funciton. Upon return, the function stack (and any variables declared local to that function) are destroyed (e.g. the memory is released for re-use), and any attempt to access the values of the array (or any variable local to that function) after the function returns results in *Undefined Behavior*.

Now regardless whether you return `x` and change your function type to `long *`, there is no need to dynamically allocate `input`, as that value is not returned.

However, if you do need to return a pointer to `x` so that the values you store are available back in the calling function, then you do need to dynamically allocate `x` as you have done. Why? When you dynamically allocate memory for `x` with `malloc` the lifetime extends from the time the memory is allocated, until it is deallocated (See **§7.22.3 Memory management functions**, in the link above). So you can dynamically allocate `x` in your function as you have done, and then declare your function as `long *memoryallocationtest(int number)` and `return x` to make the values available for use within the remainder of your program until you `free (x);`.

Which brings me to my final point. Your function, as written, fills `x`, then immediately frees `x`. While fine, in a real-world use of `x`, the `free (x);` call would not take place until you had finished making use of `x` in some meaningful way.

So in summary, there is no need to allocate for `input`, if either `x` won't fit on the stack, or you decide to `return x;` are true, then yes, a perfectly efficient way to provide memory for `x` is with `malloc`. If however, you are just using `x` in your function, and it will fit within the function stack, (it will until you reach several hundred thousand elements, architecture and compiler depdendent), then a simple declaration of an array of `long` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside memory for an array of 10 integers *statically* is done like this (the data lives on the stack part of memory.)

```
int array[10];
```

As for *dynamic* allocation, the data lives on the heap.

```
int *array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Here is a simple image that roughly describes the memory layout of a typical program:

[image]

> Is there any point of allocating and freeing space for my char-array "input" or should I just declare it like char input[32]; or is that what happens implicit anyway?

The advantage of dynamic allocation is that you need not know in advance how much memory you want to request from the OS. The disadvantage is that it is more difficult to manage dynamically allocated memory, and it is more susceptible to [external fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)#External_fragmentation). When you use malloc, what you describes **does not** happen implicitly.

If you know in advance exactly how much memory you need (exactly how long your integer array is), there is no need to use dynamic allocation (malloc), and declaring the array like "char input[32];" is totally sufficient.

Comment: See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) (otherwise, good answer)